# Determine if wall is loadbearing

Tags: walls, interior

I was planning on removing half of this wall that is on my first floor. The joists in the basement, between the first and second floor, and in the attic all run parallel to this wall. Above this room is my master bath. The wall between the bedroom and master bath is directly above this wall. In that bathroom, there is a shower stall, vanity, and toilet (nothing crazy or heavy). I began removing the wall and saw that there was a solid header above the door jam. The header was made up of two 2 x 8s that were sandwiched together and then there were two 2 x 4s under the 2 x 8s that sat on the jack studs. I've since put back the 2 x4s that are not in this picture until this can be decided. The beams that are in the room are fake beams. They are purely decoration. The walls in the basement, between the first and second floor, and in the attic all run parallel with this wall. The line on the picture of the house is showing where the wall is and the arrow in the basement picture is showing where the wall is. There are no columns in the basement as you can see. The doorway on that wall I want to remove has a 35" opening. The part of the wall that I want to take down would be about 7 feet wide.  Also, the header above the doorway is just above the door. It does not run the length of the wall that is still covered by sheetrock. With this information, do you believe this wall is loadbearing? It seems strange that they would put a solid header above the door.
[image]
[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Probably. That's all anyone can say from the information at hand. Most carpenters don't waste 2x8 or 2x10 on non-bearing headers.

Comment: I will say that just because the ceiling didn't move or "feel" like it was load bearing doesn't mean that it isn't.  It might not bear very much load, but more investigation to the framing above would be needed.

Comment: If it runs _parallel_ to the floor joists above, then it's likely _not_ load bearing. If it's _perpendicular_, then it probably _is_ load bearing. NOTE: This is _likelihood_, not guaranteed.

Comment: It's commonly _both_ parallel and perpendicular. A wall crosswise through the house often indicates a change in direction in the floor or roof framing above.

Comment: are those brown strips decorative / faux or are they load bearing beams? If they are load bearing then the wall is likely not. Please add picture of basement, and which way does the roof run?

Comment: What's with the notch in left side of the header? On the right side of the header it looks like the header is floating above the stud. Is it possible this whole wall was an add-on and the header is actually a beam (or an header that spanned a wider doorway at some point) that extends inside the wall to the right of the doorway?

Comment: What kind of roof have you got? Are you CERTAIN there’s no wall above this one on the same vertical plane? It could still be bearing roof load even with parallel joists if it is in the centerline of the roof. It also could be because of the bathtub. In some cases I could imagine a framer putting a header over a doorway if the bathtub above is going to be a point load. What’s underneath in the basement? Is there a wall or columns directly under this wall, carrying load down to the foundation?

Comment: @RibaldEddie I added more information and pictures to help. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @spuck The notch is me cutting into it. Then I stopped because I got worried because the beam seemed suspicious. Since taking this picture, I put back the two 2 x 4s that were running underneath these two 2 x 8s.

Comment: @P2000 the brown strips are fake beams that are purely decorative. I added more pictures and information to my post as well based on your request.

Comment: It looks like it’s bearing some load yes. The roof dormer probably— if you live somewhere that snows in the winter, the rafters that the dormer is attached to are going to be stressed by the snow load. The wall probably stiffens up the rafters at that point and spreads the load down to the basement just enough. What’s the span distance in the basement of those joists between the cinder block wall and the large beam? And is there anything “special” about the axis of the wall in the basement? Extra blocking? Steel plates? Doubled up joists on that axis?

Comment: @ribaldeddie The distance spanning between the two walls is 10.5 feet. I live in NJ so we get snow but generally not buckets of it. There is also a dormer on the other side of the house. It is above the kitchen. There is no wall underneath like there is in the room I'm working on. In the basement on that side, there is also no support. I added another photo showing what it looks like at the axis. At the axis, there are 4 pieces of wood that make up the beam and it sits on a cinderblock wall and also has a temporary beam that was there since we've moved in.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated pictures it seems that wall could bear some load, but it is not clear what support is provided in the basement. Sometimes existing framing can be faulty (esp. with incorrect bearing), or over done, appearing to bear a load when in fact it doesn't.

One way out of this question of load bearing or not, would be to assume it is, and add a beam over the opening. You could build a 3x 2x10 beam, and bear it at one end on the foundation wall (left in the basement pic) and on the opposite end on the existing cross beam (right in the basement pic, with the 3in drain running along it). Something like 2 2x4 at each end could suffice to support the beam.

I am not a framer, so if anyone who is comments and comes up with different dimensions and framing, I'd go with that. Perhaps a smaller beam depth would suffice, e.g. 3x 2x8, and you could even dispense with one of the top plates.

Ultimately it would take an engineer on site to provide an ultimate and warranted answer, but sometimes a good carpenter and more lumber than necessary can do very well and save you time and money.

Once you have decided which route to take, we can help you here with further tips for framing and finishing.